# How do you view the table structure for the relational data used in XPages JDBC?

Tags: xpages

The XPages JDBC application uses the derby1 connection and the examples show being able to sort the columns in ascending/descending order.  The design elements show the column headings with sortable="true" which is what I have in my app, but my columns won't sort.  You can see a table structure using the Table Meta Data listing, but that doesn't say if the data element is indexed.  Our DBA says that the index doesn't allow/disallow sorting and that I have to use the order by.

So, how is sorting being accomplished in this application when there is no event tied to the columnheader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dba is right, you can order by a unindexed column (use `ORDER BY YourColumnName` in your SQL statement). Both datasources (JdbcRowSet and JdbcQuery) allow you to specify `sqlQuery` parameter, which can contain this clause. Unfortunately you cannot use `sqlParameters` properties for sorting (this is probably because `java.sql.PreparedStatement` does not allow you specify an ORDER BY parameter).

On SSJS side, you can use `@JdbcDbColumn()` function, which allows orderBy as fifth parameter, or use your own SQL statement with `@JdbcExecuteQuery`.